# Apply rot13 (or other encryption) to all forwarded traffic on port

Tags: networking, encryption, port-forwarding

This sounds very dumb but hear me out (though it still may be).

I'm a CS student. And the collage I study in have the bright idea of blocking all incommoding SSH and VPN traffic in the name of security. Then asks all persional to go through an out-of-date and exploitable OpenVPN server to reach behind the firewall. Which made my life difficult. I want to reach my lab server from my home. But not through the old OpenVPN server.

```
---------------       ---------------            -----------------
| My home PC  | --->  | Firewall    |   -X--->   | Lab server    |
---------------       ---------------            -----------------
```

The entire thing sounds stupid to me (I'd argue someone using default passwords being a bigger issue. Anyway). I decided to figure out how solid the firewall is. Then I found that *encrypting* my traffic through [rot13](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rot13/) is good enough to fool the firewall.

```
---------------                   ---------------                         -----------------
| My home PC  |->| rot13 | --->  | Firewall     |   ----->  | rot13 | ->  | Lab server    |
---------------                   ---------------                         -----------------
```

Here's my PoC:

```bsh
# Client side:
nc -l -p 2222 | rot13 | nc my_server_ip 2222
```

```bsh
# server side:
nc -l -p 2222 -s my_server_ip | rot13 | nc localhost 22
```

Which does get the SSH handshake going when I connect to `localhost 2222`. But this is a one way link therefore the handshake doesn't complete. (contrast to the handshake packet doesn't even arrive without `rot13`).

The question is, this is an encrypted one way link. How could I make it bidirectional? So far I tried to pipe data from iptables to `rot13` and back. But I can't.

**Notes**

1. I'm not considering obfuscating proxies like `obfsproxy` since this should be easy. Don't want to use the heavy duty weapons.
2. ROT13 is only there to bypass the firewall. I'm aware that it's weak.
3. This is a question of "Hmm... could I do this?" not "should I do this?"

Comment: Do you have root access on both ends?

Comment: Ahh.. I forgot to say. Yes. I have root on both boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`socat` should do.**

The [`socat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat) tool takes care of all your needs to (bidirectionally) pipe anything anywhere. It just takes a pair of arguments, each specifying one of the things to connect together. The most interesting options in this case are `TCP:host:port`, `TCP-LISTEN:port` and `FD:` or `OPEN:`. Each argument can also be composed of a pair of these separated by `!!`, where the first element will be read and the other one will be written.

A minimal extension to your `nc`-based example could thus look something like this:

Server end:

```
mkfifo in in_rot out out_rot
rot13 < in > in_rot &
rot13 < out > out_rot &
socat TCP:localhost:22 OPEN:in_rot!!OPEN:out &
socat TCP-LISTEN:2222 OPEN:out_rot!!OPEN:in &
```

This can be simplified by getting rid of the named FIFOs and using `FD:` to refer to pipes set up in Bash.

As written, this would only be good for a single use (`socat` will exit once the connections get closed). You can either run it in an infinite loop, or set up a systemd `.socket` unit or something like `xinetd` to do the listening for you and spawn this script upon connection.

The client end can be done in a very similar way (listening on some local port and connecting to the server on 2222), or you can omit the TCP-LISTEN part and instead run the whole thing as a `ProxyCommand` from `ssh` (you can then put that into your `.ssh/config` and use ssh as if there was no tunnel).

Should you ever want to tunnel more than just a SSH connection, note that `socat` also has the `TUN:` option that will give you a full-blown tunnel interface, so you can then trivially turn this into a real VPN.

Comment: It works! Tho the firewall killed the connection the key exchange. I guess thy did more than the basics. Thanks again.